# DataType.PhoneNumber Attribute has No Effect on Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a `[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]` on a `String` field in my view model. When the phone number is displayed, however, it is rendered as a simple string with no formatting.

Another field in my view model has the `[DataType(DataType.Url)]` attribute and *it* renders correctly as an HTML element.

I have two questions then:

1. Why does the `DataType.Url` decorated field render correctly while the
   `DataType.PhoneNumber` field looks like an ordinary string of character with no phone-specific formatting?
2. How can I get the `PhoneNumber` to render as a valid phone number
       (i.e., something like `(xxx) xxx-xxxx`. If you tell me I must use a
       `DataFormat` attribute with a `DataFormatString`, then what's the
       point of even having a `DataType.PhoneNumber`?

Comment: >what's the point of even having a DataType.PhoneNumber?  to tell mobile browsers this is a dialable number.

Answer (score -1):

For your first question, Url's have a specific syntax that if not followed will not be a correct url.

Phone numbers do not have any specific format.  in the US alone you could have

xxx-xxx-xxxx

(xxx) xxx-xxxx

(xxx)xxx-xxxx

xxx.xxx.xxxx

1(xxx) xxx-xxxx

Then you get into international numbers with country code prefixes.

010 64 3 477 4000

0011 64 3 477 4000

+64 3 477 4000

All of these are valid phone numbers

`input="tel"` allows you to embed a phone number so that in a mobile(phone) browser, you can click on it and it will pre-populate the phone number in your dialer.

As for the data-annotations, they render the correct html they will have the correct html5 type tags.  It up to the browser to actually implement what it will look like on the screen or interpret how it should be validated.

Comment: Your first point about the variation in phone number formats is obviously correct and would explain why there is not a default rendering for phone numbers.

Your point about input="tel" has nothing to do with mobile devices. All browsers, not just mobile, can utilize input="tel". I have Skype installed on my desktop and clicking on an input="tel" opens Skype. 

You may not have looked at the generated HTML for DataType.PhoneNumber. The point is that there is no special HTML or formatting. It renders as a plain old String.

Comment: What I'm saying is the only use of DataType.PhoneNumber is to output "type='tel" into your html.  That's it.  It's up to the browser, skype,... whatever to interpret that.

Comment: The type="tel" does _not_ get generated in the HTML. Therefore, the browser has no way to know this was a phone number. Also, you are incorrect in that the only use of DataType.PhoneNumber is to render input="tel" (which it doesn't do anyway). By using DataType.PhoneNumber I can set up a custom display template in a file named, PhoneNumber.cshtml, which will be invoked by for all fields decorated with [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)].

Comment: EditorFor() generates <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" type="tel" value=""> when you decorate a model property with DateType.PhoneNumber

Comment: My question was not about editor templates. It was about display templates, In my MVC 5 app, @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber) produces 3125551212, with zero HTML wrapping it, just like a plain old string.